# Customize bashrc in OpenELEC

Tags: ssh, openelec

I'm running OpenELEC 3.2.0 on Raspberry Pi
I'm trying to customize `bashrc`, the same way that we create/edit `~/.bashrc` in individual GNU/Linux distributions. Which doesn't seem to be working on OpenELEC

I tried these paths:

```
/storage/.bashrc
/storage/.config/.bashrc
/storage/.config/bashrc
/storage/.config/shell.conf
```

But none of them seem to be working
(And `/storage` is the only place that we can customize things, since root partition is read-only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# printenv
```

shows that sh is the default shell, not bash!
sh executes the /storage/.profile on ssh login.

here's my quick & dirty hack to switch to bash.
make sure you have the /storage/.bashrc file and 
that it's error free.

```
# cat /storage/.profile
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/storage/bin:$PATH
TERM=xterm-color
exec bash & source /storage/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Just one more question: why bash functions aren't working? (I can move them into separate scripts of course, but I like to know why)

Comment: @ilius Can you give an example?